# Counting zeroes in binary representation of decimal number

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is my code: *edited

```
private static long zeros(long y){
    int count= 0;

    for(long i= y; i<=0; i/=2){
        if((i%2)==0) {
        count+=1;
   }
    return count;
  }
```

It has to count all the zeros that given decimal number **(long y) when method is called** contains in binary form by using **just one for loop**, but I can't figure out why this won't work

Comment: Debug it. Step through it with small values, like `y = 4`. Print out values such as `i`, `count` to see if they contain what you expect.

Comment: You're looping while i is bigger or equal to y. But the first iteration divides i by 2. So i is smaller than y, and the loop stops.

Comment: You changed your question without clarifying that in your question, making existing questions and answers suddenly not in line with your question. Don't do that - always explain if you make a change that invalidates existing answers. Now the second term of your for-loop reads `i<=0` where it first read `i>=y`. The new situation is even worse, since now it won't even get through the first iteration, unless you are dealing with negative numbers. You should check for `i != 0`.

Comment: in for loop i=y; that means that i takes the value of y until i<= 0, and every iteration i/=2; first iteration check if the number gives rest 0 if so increment counter by 1 if not do nothing and for next iteration divide i by two and do the same until the i<= 0. whats the problem ?

Comment: The second term of a for-loop has to be true for *as long as the loop runs*. The loop runs *while* the second expression is true, not *until* it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop

```
for(long i= y; i>=y; i/=2)
```

will finish after the first iteration for positive `y`s, except when `y` is zero, in which case the loop is infinite.

You should make several modifications to your program:

- Make sure `y` is not negative before entering the loop
- Add a special case producing the count of 1 when `y` is zero
- Make your loop stop when `i` reaches zero.

Comment: accidentally typed that, i edited the code in post but it wont work it seems like it wont even go into the loop when I am debugging it

Answer (score 1):

Why you simply not use :

```
long l = 853;//You Long value

//Convert Long to Binary then count the number of 0
StringUtils.countMatches(Long.toBinaryString(l), "0");
```

**Example :**

```
System.out.println("toBinaryString = " + Long.toBinaryString(l));
System.out.println("Nbr = " + StringUtils.countMatches(Long.toBinaryString(l), "0"));
```

This will print :

```
toBinaryString = 1101010101
Nbr = 4
```

Comment: *using just one for loop